# How to get a mean of a list of columns in a polars dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I want to get the average of a list of columns within a polars dataframe, but am getting stuck.  For example:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a':[1,2,3],
    'b':[4,5,6],
    'c':[7,8,9]
})

cols_to_mean = ['a','c']
```

This works:

```
df.select(pl.col(cols_to_mean))
```

In that it returns just those columns, but when I try to calculate the mean, this line

```
df.select(pl.col(cols_to_mean).mean())
```

Returns the mean of each column (while I want a column the same length as each that is the mean of them both for each row).  There isn't an option to pass an axis to the mean function.  I also try:

```
df.select(pl.mean(pl.col(cols_to_mean).mean()))
```

But this produces an error:

```
TypeError: Invalid input for `col`. Expected `str` or `DataType`, got
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What should the output be? Do you want the [mean of each row](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/list_context.html) e.g. `df.select(pl.concat_list(cols_to_mean).arr.mean())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code and the result. (as also mentioned by @jqurious and @Rakesh Chaudhary)

```py
df.select(
    col_mean = pl.concat_list(cols_to_mean).list.mean()
)

shape: (3, 1)
┌──────────┐
│ col_mean │
│ ---      │
│ f64      │
╞══════════╡
│ 4.0      │
│ 5.0      │
│ 6.0      │
└──────────┘
```

EDIT: use list instead of arr following Polars update

Comment: Playing around with this more, I was seeing the above solution has an intermediate step where it creates a column where each element is a list.  Then it takes a mean of each element in that column.  I was wondering if there really isn't a more direct route like the pandas approach: ```df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':[1,2,3],
    'b':[4,5,6],
    'c':[7,8,9]
})

df[['a','c']].mean(axis=1)```.  My best effort so far is ```df.select(
    col_mean = pl.Series(df.select(cols_to_mean).to_numpy().mean(axis=1))
)``` but that entails a round-trip to numpy

Comment: Hi @PaulFleming, the 'Polars' way of expressing axis=1 is indeed using concat_list(). Behind the scenes, concat_list() is a view on your existing data so it does not do any copies of the data. 

So this would be the most efficient way to do it in Polars.

Copying to numpy will add a roundtrip to numpy which can slow down the query.

Comment: hi @Luca, it's interesting this solution worked in the past, but maybe now an update to polars if I run this code I get: ```AttributeError: 'ExprArrayNameSpace' object has no attribute 'mean'```, have you seen this?

Comment: But I think this now gives a good result: ```df.select(cols_to_mean).mean(axis=1).alias('col_mean')```

Comment: this version works, but only on a dataframe, it's a little harder to chain than the former version

Comment: Hi @PaulFleming you are right , following Polars update the right way to do it is using list instead of arr

Comment: The only issue I'm having is that it was easier to embed the old method within a with_columns statement, however because the new method uses a select statement, it returns a dataframe, and wants a dataframe as an startingpoint (I cant yet make it work with pl.columns), but maybe I'm missing a better approach, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hi @PaulFleming, the new statement should also work with a `with_columns` context. The only difference should be a change in namespace: instead of calling `.arr.mean()`, we now call `.list.mean()`

Comment: `pl.concat_list(cols_to_mean).list.mean()` is faster than `.select(pl.col(cols_to_mean)).mean(axis=1)` I found

Comment: anybody else find this list syntax weird? why not just `pl.col(cols_to_mean).mean(axis=1)` ?

Answer (score -3):

df = pl.DataFrame({ "col1": [1, 2, 3], "col2": [4, 5, 6], "col3": [7, 8, 9] })

Comment: Please read [answer]. In particular, please make sure that your answers address the question being asked.